# Redirect to a view from a view and to a specific tab in that redirected view in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I want to redirect to another view from a view. The view i will redirect to has tabs and once I am redirected I want tab # 3 to open/selected. Tab #3 has partial view, which will open once it is selected.

Can someone help, please. If more info is needed, I can send. Here is what I have so far.

```
<script>
$(function () {
$("#tabs").tabs();
<script>
```

This is for the button that will redirect to Index view in manage controller.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to another page using javascript you can do it like this;

```
window.location.replace('Your URL to which you want to navigate goes here');
```

In the load method of the view where the tabs are, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs( { selected: null } );
    $tabs.tabs("select", 2);
});
```

Please note the 2nd argument to tabs function is a zero based index so 2 will select the 3rd tab.

If you want to pass the tab number to select in the redirect URL, you can do it as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) answer.

Comment: how about to a view and tab #3? Thanks